# Expansion of $n$-th order summation

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, polynomials

After the expansion of
$$
(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)^m
$$
how many terms (with same basis, e.g. $x_1^m$, $x_1^{m-1}x_2$, and so on) do we get?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By same basis you are trying to say same coefficient?

Comment: checkout the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Comment: @MatthewGunn Yes, the theorem is what I am looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for your attention. The theorem above is the right one for my question.

Answer (score 0):

One find $m!\over m_1!m_2!...m_n!$. This can be proved by induction, for instance, on $n$.